# Scala set vs map in for comprehension

Tags: scala

Playing around with Scala I'm facing these two similar pieces of code that puzzle me:

```
val m = Map("a"->2D, "b"->3D)

for((k, v) <- m) yield (v, k)    // Yields Map(4.0 -> a, 3.0 -> b)
for(k <- m.keys) yield (m(k), k) // Yields Set((4.0,a), (3.0,b))
```

1. Why the different behavior?
2. Is it possible to change the second comprehension so that it yields a Map instead of a Set?

I sense there is something good to learn here, any additional pointers appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that a `for` comprehension is de-sugared into `map()` and `flatMap()` (and `withFilter()`) calls. In this case, because each of your examples has a single generator (`<-`) each one becomes a single `map()` call.

Also recall that `map()` will return the same monad (wrapper type) that it was called on.

In the 1st example you're mapping over a `Map` so you get a `Map` back: from `Map[String,Double]` to `Map[Double,String]`. The tuples are transformed in to key->value pairs.

In the 2nd example you're mapping over a `Set` of elements from the keys of a `Map`, so you get a `Set` back. No tuple transformation takes place. They are left as tuples.

To get a `Map` out of the 2nd example, i.e. to get the tuples transformed, wrap the entire `for` in parentheses and tag a `.toMap` at the end.